# How to convert multiple files of the same extension?

Tags: python, xlsx, xls

I am using this code to convert ".xls" file into ".xlsx". I was successful in doing it for 1 file. But I am trying to put this in a loop so that I can convert multiple files at once.

The files have different names, so it is getting difficult for me to achieve this. This is my code :

```
import win32com.client as win32
fname = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test\\a.xls"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)

wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.
*Edit-1 : Implemented 1st solution by @Ayush, following error observed :*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\convert2.py", line 7, in <module>
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 75, in Open
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1923, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((8, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find a.xls. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `os` module to get the list of the files in the specified folder and loop through them. Try this and let me know if it worked.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
for file in dir_list:
    file_with_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_with_path)

    wb.SaveAs(file_with_path+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
    wb.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

**Edit:**

**Note: Use the above code if you want to edit those excel files too otherwise if you just want to rename the files use the code below**

```
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    file_with_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    os.rename(file_with_path, file_with_path + 'x')
```

**Note: The above code can be SLIGHTLY improved again but then you have to make sure that the below script is in the same directory as the excel files**

```
import os
[os.rename(file, file + 'x') for file in os.listdir('.')]
```

Comment: sorry, I got an error :wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 75, in Open
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1923, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((8, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find a.xls. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: I simply took the path from the code in your question. How is that possible? Can you edit your question and include a detailed error?

Comment: `os.listdir` only returns the file name. You need to add the path back in. `os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test", file)`. Likely better is to use glob, which keeps the path but lets you limit filename. `for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test\\*.xls")` .

Comment: @tdelaney : I used your approach and could solve it, thanks.

Comment: Ayush, if you add the os.path.join then this can be marked as the solution.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for pointing out the error. I didn't execute the code once that's why I sort of overlooked it. Thanks

Comment: @AyushGupta Thanks for the solution. I am using yours as my solution is slower. However I have 2000 files that need to be changed. Is there any way to speed it up. At present its like taking like 30 mins on my Intel i7 laptop.

Comment: @2014GAM I was thinking the same but then I thought that maybe you have to edit those excel files too that's why I didn't say anything before. But don't worry, I have the solution which is much faster than this.

Comment: I have made the edits. Choose the code that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by looking into some other answers, here is the code :

```
import os
import os.path
import win32com.client as win32
rootdir = u'"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test"'
for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
    for fn in filenames:
        filedir = os.path.join(parent, fn)
        print(filedir)
 
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filedir)
        # xlsx: FileFormat=51
        # xls:  FileFormat=56,
        wb.SaveAs(filedir+"x", FileFormat = 51) 
        wb.Close()                                 
        excel.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: this will process all the subdirectories - that may be good but be aware.

Comment: I have fixed the code take a look now. By the by, you don't want to be using ```os.walk``` because it walks the current directory and the directories inside and so on. Maybe you need it, maybe you don't. But here you clearly don't, so don't use ```os.walk```